# Powershell how to bulk rename files containing DTS 1080p 720p x264 etc

Tags: powershell, rename

I am trying to create a powershell script to rename media files that have a bunch of descriptions in the file name like DTS,1080P,720P,x264,DVD etc...

Is there some sort of or condition that can be used in the replace option?

Comment: Question is NOT clear, at least to me. Can you can provide a file name and what you want it to be renamed to?

Answer (score 2):

To be honest, I'd probably just do it the lazy way and replace all the terms you don't want with nothing, do the same with underscores if desired (included in my example code), trim spaces from the end, and then rename the file (I just use the .MoveTo method).

```
gci "C:\Movies" | %{$_.MoveTo("$($_.Directory)\$(($_.BaseName -replace '(?i)(1080p|720p|DTS|DVD|x264|_)').TrimEnd(" "))$($_.Extension)")}
```

Comment: Brilliant.  Worked for me.

Comment: I took out the underscore as many of the file names need it.  But I had one minor issue with the script.  I added an entry .1080p_8000 and .1080p_12000.  It won't remove the 8000 or 12000 chars.

Answer (score 0):

Use the -filter parameter

```
$count = 0 
ls -filter "*1080p*" | % { Rename-item $_ "NewFile$count.ext";$count++}
```

Careful, that will rename all files in current directory with "1080p" in the name to newfile0.ext.. just an example